# getting mysql deadlock because this query is taking to long

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have one query that is taking too long(> 5 minutes) and creating deadlocks

virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming has 1115501 rows

virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_media has 25752 rows

I do not think these are supper big tables.

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming i
     LEFT JOIN virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_media m ON m.messageID = i.messageID
WHERE i.from_id = '0'
  AND i.sms_type = 0
ORDER BY received DESC
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming` (                                                    
 `messageID` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `from` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `eventType` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `text` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `time` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `to` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `state` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `messageURL` varchar(105) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `applicationId` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `direction` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `vid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `from_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `received` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `process_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `sms_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
 `acted_upon` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',                                                    
 KEY `vidx_1` (`messageID`),                                                    
 KEY `vidx_2` (`vid`),                                                    
 KEY `vidx_3` (`sms_type`),                                                    
 KEY `vidx_4` (`from_id`),                                                    
 KEY `vidx_5` (`time`,`messageID`),                                                    
 KEY `vidx_6` (`vid`,`process_status`,`acted_upon`),                                                    
 KEY `vidx_7` (`vid`,`process_status`,`time`),                                                    
 KEY `vidx_8` (`from_id`,`sms_type`,`messageID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_media` (
 `messageID` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
 `media` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `vabimind_1` (`messageID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

When I do an explain plan

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | i |  | ref | "virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_sms_type_index,virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_from_id_index,vidx_8" | vidx_8 | 7 | "const,const" | 28670 | 100 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | m |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 25761 | 100 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |

I tried adding the index that was suggested

The query still takes 20 minutes and the record count returned is 190682

Thanks for any help or insight

Comment: far more helpful to just see output of `show create table virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming`, which will include all the indexes and their names.  please edit and add that and output of `show create table virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_media`

Comment: @ysth table creates added

Comment: no, please show the output of `show create table...`, not your original create statements.

Comment: @ysth updated to show the create table

Comment: What is the format of your `messageID`s? The join is between `messageID`s but with different character sets (latin1 vs utf8). uft8(mb3) is deprecated and you should probably be using utf8mb4. Neither table has a primary key, is this intentional? Why are you using MyISAM, as opposed to InnoDB?

Comment: @user1191247 i just updated to 5.7 that is probably why. I need to convert these tables to InnoDB, thanks

Comment: If you're getting an actual deadlock, instead of just a timeout, there must be contention between an INSERT or UPDATE operation elsewhere in your application and this query. Please clarify. You may be able to remediate that with a [dirty read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted) if you're not worried about your result set containing partial-transaction data from other parts of your app. But be careful.

Comment: It is not possible to get a deadlock with MyISAM tables, because MyISAM does not support transactions. The OP is using the term deadlock inaccurately. They may be getting lock timeouts, but not a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that your tables use different character sets. This prevents the join to the second table from using an index.

My recommendation:

```
ALTER TABLE virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_media CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

utf8mb4 is the default character set in current versions of MySQL. I think it's uncommon that you would ever need the other character sets.

Really it's the collation that needs to be the same in both columns you join. Of course they need to be the same character set as well, to have the same collation.

A further optimization can be to add an index that eliminates the filesort.

```
ALTER TABLE virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming ADD INDEX vidx_9 (from_id, sms_type, received);
```

I also recommend using InnoDB over MyISAM. InnoDB is the default storage engine in MySQL since 2010, and it has a lot of advantages over MyISAM, including performance. See my answer to [MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717)

```
ALTER TABLE virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming_media ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

How many rows do you have where the from_id=0 and sms_type=0 out of the 1115501 rows? This ratio will determine if the optimizer chooses an index.

You can create an index that matched better with the query:

```
create index vidx_8
on virt_assist_bandwidth_incoming (from_id, sms_type, messageID);
```

Also, try adhering the datatypes, if `i.from_id` is an integer, use `i.from_id=0` instead of `i.from_id='0'`.

There was no table description, so there is no info on from which table the `received` comes from.

Comment: i tried adding the index, i change the '0' to 0 and the query still took 20 minutes to return 190682 rows

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN` look like after the index has been added?

Comment: i have updated the description to reflect the explain after the new index was added

Comment: @randy - `INT_column = '0'` is ok.  `CHAR_col = 0` is inefficient